# Capturing Outlook address with Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I've a custom VBA function in Excel that's supposed to pick up the associated Office user's email address. It triggers arbitrarily for some users - sometimes it works, other times it doesn't.

My end-users aren't all on the latest version of Excel, but this is the only VBA function that's causing trouble. For affected users it tends to work more the first time they open the file, and then goes inert on subsequent opens.

```vb
Function UserName() As String
    Dim OL As Object, olAllUsers As Object, oExchUser As Object, oentry As Object, myitem As Object
    Dim User As String
    
    Set OL = CreateObject("outlook.application")
    Set olAllUsers = OL.Session.AddressLists.Item("All Users").AddressEntries
    
    User = OL.Session.CurrentUser.Name
    
    Set oentry = olAllUsers.Item(User)
    
    Set oExchUser = oentry.GetExchangeUser()
    
    UserName = oExchUser.PrimarySmtpAddress
    
End Function
```

I tried some solutions from the web to no avail, as well as trying to force the cell to recalculate, but it seems that for impacted users once the function has decided it doesn't do anything, recalculation is irrelevant.

Comment: My guess is that your code is accessing the Global Address List. It has always been buggy but to troubleshoot you can open Outlook on a machine that cannot retrieve the user's email address and open the Global Address List. Search for that users email address in All Users. Compare that with a machine that successfully works. 
Maybe you can use another entry in the GAL (Not All Users).

Comment: I would recommend a query to AD instead of assuming that Outlook can resolve the address, as you've seen it can't be reliable.

Comment: How would you structure that query?

Answer (score 0):

The code can be simplified a bit:

```
Function UserName() As String
Dim OL As Object, oExchUser As Object, oentry As Object, myitem As Object
Dim User As String

Set OL = CreateObject("outlook.application")

'
' use NameSpace.Logon if required
'

Set oentry = OL.Session.CurrentUser.AddressEntry

'
' here you can also check whether it is an Exchange account
'

Set oExchUser = oentry.GetExchangeUser()

UserName = oExchUser.PrimarySmtpAddress

End Function
```